# special case - Second fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus

By the second fundamental theorem of calculus I know that
$$f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^b f'(t)dt.$$
So the following should be correct
$$f(x,t)-f(y,t)= \int_y^x \partial_sf(s,t)ds \quad \text{ for all $t$. }$$
Am I right?

Comment: That is correct. What exactly are your doubts?

Comment: You may have slightly more conditions to impose on $f$, but otherwise makes sense

Comment: @MartinR $t$ acts as a constant, so no doubts really. But it was one of these times that even it seems obvious, you look for extra confirmation.Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to formalize it, for fixed $t$ set
$$g(s)=f(s,t)
$$
Next, apply the definitions of derivatives and of partial derivatives to justify that
$$g'(s) = \partial_s f(s,t)
$$
Finally, apply the 2nd F.T.C. to $g$ and use those two equations above to substitute.